# handling multiple submit buttons in one form ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to develop some web page in Asp.Net and C# which almost look like facebook login page where user can sign in at top of the page and sign up at the bottom, how should I do that? and when the focuses are on the textboxs of sign in part and the user hit the Enter it should go to Sign in method,

I already searched in stackoverflow about it and it seems all questions which already asked were about Asp.Net MVC which I'm not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a single event to multiple button clicks -

```
topButton.Click += SignInButtonClick;
bottomButton.Click += SignInButtonClick;

void SignInButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here

}
```

I presume in your case the same logic will run for both buttons, you could find out which button was clicked using `sender` argument that is passed into the function.

As an example, let's say I have an aspx page and I add a button to it called 'Button1' I can then add a click event via Visual Studio and it will create a methiod to handle the click event for me called `Button1_Click`. The method will be automatically linked to the button as the [`AutoEventWireup` up property in c# is set to true by default](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/17/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx).

Now, if I add a second button and call it 'Button2' but I want that button to fire the same event handler as the one used for Button1, I could add this code to the pages 'Page_Load' event handler

`Button2.Click += Button1_Click;`

Both buttons would then cause the 'Button1_Click' method to run when clicked.

Comment: thanks.sorry I can't understand how the first 2 lines work. could you give me any link to see how this work?

Comment: @ePezhman - I don't think this is what you want, this code simply allows 2 buttons to perform the same event when clicked. See my answer for how to trigger the correct button event when the user presses enter on a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

you rather use html Controls then Asp.net Control and can use Jquery to perform the loginb or signup

```
    $('#login').click(function(event)
    {
      // call
      // $.ajax(),$.get or $.post method for ajax call
     });
    $('#signup').click(function(event)
    {
      // call
      // $.ajax(),$.get or $.post method for ajax call
     });
    </script>

    <form id="form1">
    <input type="button" value="login" id="login"/>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
    <input type="button" value="signup" id="signup"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can connect multiple buttons to the same method by doing something like in the page load:

```
lbTest1.Click += Test_Click;
lbTest2.Click += Test_Click;

void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //your code here 
}
```

you can use the enter button to fire the method of a button by wrapping both the textbox as the button in a panel and set the `defaultbutton` property of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to wrap the related controls (e.g. the signup controls) in a Panel control, and set the DefaultButton property on the Panel. You can read about it in [this tutorial](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/defaultbutton-panel-aspnet.aspx)

Comment: @ePezhman Can you get the sample version to work? You will probably have to post your code if we are to help further

Comment: I couldn't get any sample code, it seemed the link was broken